# Add extra external column to flat file source

Tags: ssis

I have a simple ssis package (2005) which reads a fixed width flat file source and dumps into a table. File so far had 5 columns, last column being 50 length. Now the format changed, a new  column is added(length 4)at the end and previous 50 length column is only 10 length now.

I figured it should be very simple, just go to advanced editor of the source under data flow, and under external columns, modify  Column4 (my columns are named Column0 through 4) and change its length to 10, then 'add column' and name it Column5 etc. But when I add, new Column always gets added above the current last column (Column4).

How do I get to add a new column in the end without having to redo the whole Columns.

(Note: I oversimplified my case, my number of columns is really big and I would hate to have to do the whole mapping all over again... Please help!)

Comment: Try selecting not the last column, but 'Output Columns' node and then click 'Add Column'. Works for me.

Comment: @Aryadev- Thanks. I kinda renamed the columns and did my new column, but it complains that my metadata has changed. Is there a work around?

Comment: Workaround is to set ValidateExternalMetadata to 'False'. Not sure if it won't give an error at runtime though.

Comment: To fix your metadata issue, make sure that your Output Column's ExternalMetadataID matches the "ID" column the External Column that is mapped to it.

Comment: @Aryadev- In general, is it possible to handle say column width change on a column/ or multiple columns with minimal changes, without having to redo the whole mappings?

Comment: @Brian, not with the standard components. To have such flexibility you'd have to write a custom script in VB or C#.