# How do I change flat file source format in SSIS when it's inside a foreach loop?

Tags: foreach, ssis

My flat file connection manager has no file name selected because it's inside a foreach loop.  With no file name selected, I can't add any new columns.  These questions don't have the "no file name" issue, so they didn't work for me:

[Add extra external column to flat file source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523098/add-extra-external-column-to-flat-file-source)

[How to change flat file source using foreach loop container in an SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913499/how-to-change-flat-file-source-using-foreach-loop-container-in-an-ssis-package)

How do I add a new column to my file format?

Here are my flat file connection manager and foreach loop:

[image]
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281237/ssis-flat-files-with-variable-column-numbers

Comment: That's not related at all.  I read that question before I posted.  It's about SSIS ignoring if you have more or fewer columns than it is expecting.  Is that why I got the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote.  The first answer in the link I posted explains how you can handle dynamic file structures.  It is not easy, though.

Comment: Why can you not select a file name, then setup the structure?

Comment: I can, but I can't save unless I leave the bogus/hard-coded file name in there.

Comment: If you're using a foreach loop container to cycle through filenames, then the bogus/hard-coded name won't matter.  If it causes a run-time error because the file doesn't exist, then change the `DelayValidation` property in your `Abc` connection manager to `True`.

Comment: You're exactly right.  When I put anything in the "File name:" field, I can do what I need to.  Once I save the _package_, the file name is automatically cleared out.  Thank you for the help.  Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select a file name in your `Abc` flat file connection manager, then setup the structure.

If you're using a foreach loop container to cycle through filenames, then the file you choose won't matter -- it's used for design only.

If you get a run-time error because the file doesn't exist, then change the `DelayValidation` property in your `Abc` connection manager to `True`.